# PowerMockito.whenNew() works fine with Junit test but dont work with TestNg test

Tags: java, junit, testng, powermockito

I'm using TestNG to unit test and mock my application.

My problem is that when I use `PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassB.class)` method and debug in `ClassA`, I found that `objB` is the original not mocked one.
After many investigations, I used

> import org.junit.Test;

instead of

> import org.testng.annotations.Test;

and try using Junit test instead of TestNG.
What was surprising is that it's returned the expected value with JUnit(666), but with TestNG returned (15) which is not expected.

All of the classes and the pom file is below

```
package unit.test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ClassA.class, ClassB.class })
public class App {
    @Test
    public void shoudlReturn666() throws Exception {
        ClassB mockB = PowerMockito.mock(ClassB.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockB.get15()).thenReturn(666);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassB.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockB);
        Assert.assertTrue(new ClassA().callB() == 666);
    }
}
```

Class A --

```
package unit.test;
public class ClassA {
    public int callB() {
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
        return objB.get15();
    }
}
```

Class B --

```
package unit.test;
public class ClassB {
    public int get15() {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

Pom file

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Result is :

```
                [TestNG] Running:
              C:\Users\Wael Elkholy\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--514551319\testng-customsuite.xml

            FAILED: shoudlReturnTheCValue
            junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
                at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
                at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
                at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:27)
                at unit.test.App.shoudlReturnTheCValue(App.java:17)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:696)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:882)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1189)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
                at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
                at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
                at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
                at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
                at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
                at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
                at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
                at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
                at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


            ===============================================
                Default test
                Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
            ===============================================


            ===============================================
            Default suite
            Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
            ===============================================

            [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@2752f6e2: 59 ms
            [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@48140564: 20 ms
            [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@c818063: 65 ms
            [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@7dc36524: 127 ms
            [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 18 ms
            [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2133c8f8: 18 ms
```

Is any problem with my code?

Comment: If I understand the question well, you are asking how to migrate your junit working test to a testng test? Could you share your failing testng test?

Comment: Actually i'm using testng but as i mentioned, this scenario is failed with testng while it's succeed with Junit...please revise my question..i edited it

Comment: I'd like to see your failing TestNG test because `@RunWith` won't work with TestNG.

Comment: i updated the code and also shared failing of testng, i want to know how can using PowerMockito.whenNew() with Testng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the PowerMock documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage):

```
@PrepareForTest({ ClassA.class, ClassB.class })
public class App extends PowerMockTestCase {
    @Test
    public void shoudlReturn666() throws Exception {
        ClassB mockB = PowerMockito.mock(ClassB.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockB.get15()).thenReturn(666);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassB.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockB);
        Assert.assertTrue(new ClassA().callB() == 666);
    }
}
```